# Trouble with Scope and for.each in node.js

Tags: node.js, foreach

Ok, I'm a total noob with most things coding, but have been having some success teaching myself but I'm stumped. I need to add a forEach loop to some of my code, and I know I could just manually type this out twice instead of using a loop, but that doesn't teach me anything.

So, I have the following code that works, and waits for one minute before executing the next block (API requirements)

```
async function main() {

        systemOps(function(data){
            console.log('Updating Operations Data...')
            if (data == null) {
                console.log('No Operations Data Received for period requested.')
            } 
            else {
                updateDBOps('system_operations',data)
            }
        })
    }
    await sleep(60000);

    ...next function here...
}
```

What I want to do is to be able to run this same code, but pass in a location variable to the systemOps function from an array of locations, and pull data for each location, waiting for 60 sec in between.

Essentially, I am trying to do this, in a pseud-not right at all-kind of way:

```
locations = [location1, location2]

async function main() {
     locations.forEach(location =>    //This is not correct, i know...but how do I do this...can't seem to sort it
        systemOps(function(location,data){
            console.log('Updating Operations Data...')
            if (data == null) {
                console.log('No Operations Data Received for period requested.')
            } 
            else {
                updateDBOps('system_operations',data)
            }
        })
    }
    await sleep(60000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot...figured it out.

```
    OpsLocations.forEach(location => {
        OpsDownloader(location,'operation',function(data){
            console.log('Updating Operations Data from ....')
            if (data == null) {
                console.log('No Operations Data Received for period requested.')
            } 
            else {
                updateDBOps('operations',data)
            }
        })
    })
```